# How to change preloading function?

Tags: jquery, image, loading, image-preloader

I need help with the code on my site, http://www.luischales.com/miami-quinces-photography.html . the first time you open it the slide don't start until all images are loaded (i think), and clients don't like to wait so my question is, can someone point me to a way to load the images on demand? or at least load the first images and then the other ones?

***CODE***

```
   //<![CDATA[
        $(function() {
            var $tf_bg              = $('#tf_bg'),
                $tf_bg_images       = $tf_bg.find('img'),
                $tf_bg_img          = $tf_bg_images.eq(0),
                $tf_thumbs          = $('#tf_thumbs'),
                total               = $tf_bg_images.length,
                current             = 0,
                $tf_content_wrapper = $('#tf_content_wrapper'),
                $tf_next            = $('#tf_next'),
                $tf_prev            = $('#tf_prev'),
                $tf_loading         = $('#tf_loading');

            //preload the images                
            $tf_bg_images.preload({
                onComplete  : function(){
                    $tf_loading.hide();
                    init();
                }
            });

            //shows the first image and initializes events
            function init(){
                //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                //set the returned values and show the image
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                }).fadeIn();

                //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
            $(window).bind('resize',function(){
                var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                $tf_bg_img.css({
                    width   : dim.width,
                    height  : dim.height,
                    left    : dim.left,
                    top     : dim.top
                });
            });

                //expand and fit the image to the screen
                $('#tf_zoom').live('click',
                    function(){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;

                        var $this   = $(this);
                        if($this.hasClass('tf_zoom')){
                            resize($tf_bg_img);
                            $this.addClass('tf_fullscreen')
                                 .removeClass('tf_zoom');
                        }
                        else{
                            var dim = getImageDim($tf_bg_img);
                            $tf_bg_img.animate({
                                width   : dim.width,
                                height  : dim.height,
                                top     : dim.top,
                                left    : dim.left
                            },350);
                            $this.addClass('tf_zoom')
                                 .removeClass('tf_fullscreen'); 
                        }
                    }
                );

                //click the arrow down, scrolls down
                $tf_next.bind('click',function(){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;
                        scroll('tb');
                });

                //click the arrow up, scrolls up
                $tf_prev.bind('click',function(){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                    return false;
                    scroll('bt');
                });

                //mousewheel events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
                $(document).mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;

                    if(delta > 0)
                        scroll('bt');
                    else
                        scroll('tb');
                    return false;
                });

                //key events - down / up button trigger the scroll down / up
                $(document).keydown(function(e){
                    if($tf_bg_img.is(':animated'))
                        return false;

                    switch(e.which){
                        case 38:    
                            scroll('bt');
                            break;  

                        case 40:    
                            scroll('tb');
                            break;
                    }
                });
            }

            //show next / prev image
            function scroll(dir){
                //if dir is "tb" (top -> bottom) increment current, 
                //else if "bt" decrement it
                current = (dir == 'tb')?current + 1:current - 1;

                //we want a circular slideshow, 
                //so we need to check the limits of current
                if(current == total) current = 0;
                else if(current < 0) current = total - 1;

                //flip the thumb
                $tf_thumbs.flip({
                    direction   : dir,
                    speed       : 400,
                    onBefore    : function(){
                        //the new thumb is set here
                        var content = '<span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom"><\/span>';
                        content     +='<img src="' + $tf_bg_images.eq(current).attr('longdesc') + '" alt="Thumb' + (current+1) + '"/>';
                        $tf_thumbs.html(content);
                }
                });

                //we get the next image
                var $tf_bg_img_next = $tf_bg_images.eq(current),
                    //its dimentions
                    dim             = getImageDim($tf_bg_img_next),
                    //the top should be one that makes the image out of the viewport
                    //the image should be positioned up or down depending on the direction
                        top = (dir == 'tb')?$(window).height() + 'px':-parseFloat(dim.height,10) + 'px';

                //set the returned values and show the next image   
                    $tf_bg_img_next.css({
                        width   : dim.width,
                        height  : dim.height,
                        left    : dim.left,
                        top     : top
                    }).show();

                //now slide it to the viewport
                    $tf_bg_img_next.stop().animate({
                        top     : dim.top
                    },700);

                //we want the old image to slide in the same direction, out of the viewport
                    var slideTo = (dir == 'tb')?-$tf_bg_img.height() + 'px':$(window).height() + 'px';
                    $tf_bg_img.stop().animate({
                        top     : slideTo
                    },700,function(){
                    //hide it
                        $(this).hide();
                    //the $tf_bg_img is now the shown image
                        $tf_bg_img  = $tf_bg_img_next;
                    //show the description for the new image
                        $tf_content_wrapper.children()
                                           .eq(current)
                                           .show();
            });
                //hide the current description  
                    $tf_content_wrapper.children(':visible')
                                       .hide()

            }

            //animate the image to fit in the viewport
            function resize($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h;

                if(i_w > i_h){
                    new_w   = w_w;
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;

                    if(new_h > w_h){
                        new_h   = w_h;
                        new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                    }
                }   
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }

                $img.animate({
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    top     : '0px',
                    left    : '0px'
                },350);
            }

            //get dimentions of the image, 
            //in order to make it full size and centered
            function getImageDim($img){
                var w_w = $(window).width(),
                    w_h = $(window).height(),
                    r_w = w_h / w_w,
                    i_w = $img.width(),
                    i_h = $img.height(),
                    r_i = i_h / i_w,
                    new_w,new_h,
                    new_left,new_top;

                if(r_w > r_i){
                    new_h   = w_h;
                    new_w   = w_h / r_i;
                }
                else{
                    new_h   = w_w * r_i;
                    new_w   = w_w;
                }


                return {
                    width   : new_w + 'px',
                    height  : new_h + 'px',
                    left    : (w_w - new_w) / 2 + 'px',
                    top     : (w_h - new_h) / 2 + 'px'
                };
                }
        });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: **Quote OP**: _"can someone point me to a way to load the images on demand?"_... by default that's how the browser works when you **don't** preload images.

Comment: Thank you Sparky672, i ask the question cause i read somewhere that sometime you just need to change a few things on the code to make then work, like 0 is no and 1 is yes, so maybe there is a way to tell the scrip not to preload. I just need it to load faster.

Comment: You'll wait for all images to load up front or you'll wait for each image to load separately.  Either way, it still takes the same exact amount of time for each image to load.  People use pre-loading to get it all out of the way up front.  You cannot make the images load faster unless you make the file sizes smaller.

Comment: well you second option wait for each image to load is what i what i want to try, i think this way as soon a you open the page you see an image not a black background.

Comment: Second option is simply the default browser behavior.  Just get rid of your pre-loader function.  But the visitor will still have to wait for that first image to download... it's not coming from the server by magic.  Again, if loading speed is the root issue, then use Photoshop to make the image files smaller so they transfer faster.  [Your first image file is almost 450 KB](http://www.luischales.com/images/photo/quinces-1/luis-chales-quinces-sweet-16-photography-01.JPG); surely you can reduce that substantially.

Comment: Using [your first image](http://www.luischales.com/images/photo/quinces-1/luis-chales-quinces-sweet-16-photography-01.JPG), I was able to get it [down to 150 KB with almost no noticeable loss of quality](http://i46.tinypic.com/dfwnwg.jpg).  That's a 67% reduction so it's going to load 3 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to exclude the first image from your jQuery selector:

```
$('.photos').not('.exclude-photo').preload();
```

Another option may be this [jQuery Image Preload Plugin](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload) to see if the API is more in line with what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you @juddlyon, but how can i do that? or where do i have to go to exclude it? sorry man but i have no idea on all this.